# Will Array.shift permanently remove the first object from the array or just while it is being used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating an array of games, `@games = Games.all`, in my GamesController

I have a method that pulls out the first object in an array and places it in a variable if today's date matches the date of the object.

```
def game_today?
    @todays_game = @games.shift if Time.now.strftime("%_m/%d")[1..-1] == @games.first.date.strftime("%_m/%d")[1..-1]
end
```

Say we have an array `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

If the date matches the date of `array[0]`, and its pulled out TODAY, will that object still be gone tomorrow? in other words, will the #2 be the new `array[0]`, with the whole array being

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

Or, will it revert back to `[1, 2, 3, 4]` after its work is done.

I want to permanently alter the array when I do `Array.shift`

Comment: Just out of curiosity: you could have just ran the code and see what happens in about one tenth of the time it took you to write this question, let alone the time you had to wait for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is permanent, and is sadly not in line with the convention that mutating method names end with a !.

Comment: Lastly, I'm loading Games data via a seeds file, do I need to remove the object that is pulled with .shift from the seeds file as well? How does that work?

Comment: If you want to alter the contents of your database, you will need to write your changes. That's a different matter than your question about the behavior of Array#shift, and I can't answer that without knowing your context. I think it would be best to open a new question for that.

Comment: There is no such convention. There *is* a convention, that if there are *two* methods with the same name, then the one which is *more surprising* gets a bang. But there is nothing surprising about a method named `shift` being destructive. The name already tells you that.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be sharing state between requests this way.

You should be querying the correct record from the database on each request, trying to hold all the games in memory and access the correct one from there.

If you want to permanently remove a record, you need to delete it from the database.